# How to check if all element of a list is inside of a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

Im parsing a website to catch available products and there sizes. Theres 3 products loaded. Theres a list named 'find_id_1' that houses 3 elements, each element has the product name and their variant ids. I made 2 other list one named keywords and one named negative. the keywords list houses the keywords that my desired product title should have. If any elements from the negative list are in the product title then I don't want that product.

```
found_product = []
keywords = ['YEEZY','BOOST','700']
negative = ['INFANTS','KIDS']

find_id_1 = ['{"id":2069103968384,"title":
"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2","handle":**"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-june-6"**,
[{"id":19434310238336,"parent_id":2069103968384,"available":true,
"sku":"193093889925","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":30000,"options"', 

'{"id":2069103935616,"title":"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2 KIDS","handle":
"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-kids-june-6",`
["10.5k"],"option1":"10.5k","option2":"",
`"option3":"","option4":""},{"id":19434309845120,"parent_id":2069103935616,
"available":false,"sku":"193093893625","featured_image":null,
"public_title":null,"requires_shipping":true,"price":18000,"options"',

'{"id":2069104001152,"title":"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2 INFANTS",
"handle":**"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-infants-june-6"***,`
["4K"],"option1":"4k","option2":"",`
"option3":"","option4":""},{"id":161803398876,"parent_id":2069104001152,
"available":false,"sku":"193093893724",
"featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":15000,"options"']
```

I've tried using a for loop to iterate through every element in find_info_1 then creating another for loop that iterates through every element in keyword and negative but i get the wrong product. Heres my code:

```
for product in find_id_1:
     for key in keywords:
         for neg in negative:
             if key in product:
                 if neg not in product:
                     found_product = product
```

It prints the following:

```
'{"id":2069104001152,"title":"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2 INFANTS",
"handle":"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-infants-june-6,`
["4K"],"option1":"4k","option2":"",`
"option3":"","option4":""},
{"id":161803398876,"parent_id":2069104001152,
"available":false,"sku":"193093893724",
"featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":15000,"options"']
```

Im trying to get it to return element 0 from find_info_1 because thats the only one that doesn't have any of the elements from the list negative. Would using a for loop be the best and fastest way to iterate through my list? Thank you! Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should'nt treat a json data as a string. Just parse the json using json library so you can check just the title of the product. As the product list and  the specification of each of the product get bigger, the time taken for iteration increases.

To answer your question, you can simply do

```
for product in find_id_1:
    if any(key in product for key in keywords):
        if not any(neg in product for neg in negative):
            found_product.append(product)
```

this will get you the element as per your specification. however I made some changes to your data, just to make it a valid python code..

```
found_product = []
keywords = ['YEEZY','BOOST','700']
negative = ['INFANTS','KIDS']

find_id_1 = [""""'{"id":2069103968384,"title":
"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2","handle":**"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-june-6"**,
[{"id":19434310238336,"parent_id":2069103968384,"available":true,
"sku":"193093889925","featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":30000,"options"'""",

""""'{"id":2069103935616,"title":"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2 KIDS","handle":
"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-kids-june-6",`
["10.5k"],"option1":"10.5k","option2":"",
`"option3":"","option4":""},{"id":19434309845120,"parent_id":2069103935616,
"available":false,"sku":"193093893625","featured_image":null,
"public_title":null,"requires_shipping":true,"price":18000,"options"'""",

""""'{"id":2069104001152,"title":"\nYEEZY BOOST 700 V2 INFANTS",
"handle":**"yeezy-boost-700-v2-vanta-infants-june-6"***,`
["4K"],"option1":"4k","option2":"",`
"option3":"","option4":""},{"id":161803398876,"parent_id":2069104001152,
"available":false,"sku":"193093893724",
"featured_image":null,"public_title":null,
"requires_shipping":true,"price":15000,"options"'"""]



for product in find_id_1:
    if any(key in product for key in keywords):
        if not any(neg in product for neg in negative):
            found_product.append(product)


print(found_product)
```

Comment: thanks so much this worked. I was trying to parsed it by using json but there was so many junk that i parsed out before i was able to bring it down to this small chunk of info